# String Comparision : Why we have different output for below cases

Tags: c#, string

Why we have different output for below cases:

```
object obj = "Int32";
string str1 = "Int32";
string str2 = typeof(int).Name;
Console.WriteLine(obj == str1); // true
Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); // true
Console.WriteLine(obj == str2); // false !?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this is quite simple:

When you compare an `object` with a `string`, a reference comparison is used, which will only be true if both objects have the same reference.

When you compare strings a string comparison is used, which will be true if the string contents are the same regardless of whether they are the same reference.

In your third comparison you are using an `object` comparison where you are comparing two strings with identical contents but with different references, so it will return false.

The added complication is that the first two strings have the same reference because they are compile-time constants and have been [`interned` by the compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that they refer to the same string in memory.

I've annotated your original code with this explanation:

```
object obj = "Int32";            // As a compile-time constant string, this will be interned.
string str1 = "Int32";           // This is also interned, so has the same reference as obj
string str2 = typeof(int).Name;  // Same contents as str1, but a different reference 
                                 // (created at runtime, so it wasn't interned)
Console.WriteLine(obj == str1);  // Reference comparison: true because the references are the same
Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); // String comparison: true because the string contents are the same.
Console.WriteLine(obj == str2);  // Reference comparison: false because the references different.
```

Also:

- If you are using Resharper it actually warns you for the first and last comparison, saying: "Possible unintended reference comparison".
- You can get the same result by declaring str2 as follows:

  string str2 = string.Concat("Int", "32");

Comment: This answer could be even better with a note about how all identical string literals are the same object, because of interning.

Comment: Yes, I could see "Possible unintended reference comparison"                   With string str2 = string.Concat("Int", "32"); producing the same output but if I write string str2 = "Int" + "32"; it is actually true..is there any difference

Comment: @BhuwanPandey Yes, `str2 = "Int" + "32"` is concatenated by the compiler at compile-time, and therefore is identical to `str2 = "Int32"`, and it will therefore be interned with all other instances of that string at compile-time.

Comment: Yes but string str2 = string.Concat("Int", "32"); is also concatinated at compile time to become "Int32", and also + operator actually compiles into a String.Concat call.....so why we have different result for both

Comment: @BhuwanPandey No it's not concatenated at compile time when you use `string.Concat()`. Try doing `const str2 = string.Concat("Int", "32");` for example.

Comment: Yes I got your point it is throwing The expression being assigned to str2 must be constant but when I use + operator it in turn will call the string.Concat only

Comment: @BhuwanPandey What happens is that the compiler itself will concatenate constant strings that use the `+` operator, and it may or may not internally use `String.Concat()` internally to do that. (Chances are the older compiler doesn't use `String.Concat()` since it's not written in C#. The new Roslyn compiler is written in C#, so it may use `String.Concat() behind the scenes. However the important thing is to note the difference between compile-time and run-time concatenation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80776/discussion-between-bhuwan-pandey-and-matthew-watson).

Answer (score 1):

The `obj == str2` line used **reference comparison**. Whereas the `obj == str1` line did not.

### Why?

The `string` type in .NET is an implicit **reference type**. But it's not at the same time. It's one of those types that is technically a **reference type**, but it's been programmed to act like a **value type**, and is **immutable**, meaning it is not directly modified.

When you create a new `string`, a reference is allocated for it and that reference is what your `string` variable holds. You get to do all sorts of things with that `string`, but you can never change it. If you reassign the value it will merely create a new reference.

In this instance, the `obj == str1` line used **reference comparison**, but the references actually matched. Because they were both hard-coded, the compiler, and .NET, can use the same reference for each. (As we said before, strings are immutable.) You should read the `interning` link Matthew posted for more information on that.

### So, if the strings match, why did .NET create a different reference?

Consider the **significant** amount of objects you could create in memory. If, at any time, you created a new `string` and .NET went through **all** of the other strings to find one that matched, your programme would be **phenomenally slow.** You would barely get any real work done.

So, .NET optimizes this away. If you change your code a bit, you'll see what I mean.

```
object obj = "Int32";
string str1 = typeof(int).Name;
string str2 = typeof(int).Name;
Console.WriteLine(obj == str1); // false
Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2); // true
Console.WriteLine(obj == str2); // false !?
```

The `str1 == str2` line still returns true, because it's actually **comparing the strings**, whereas the `obj == str1` line is now false, because it's comparing the references of those as well.